# Filling up gaps in matrix's rows

Tags: matlab

Let `g` be a matrix containing ones\zeroes. I want to fill up gaps of zeros (complete ones sequences) in the rows of `g` which are smaller then a given `k`. 
For example fill up with ones all gaps smaller then three zeros. This code will work:

```
        [m,n]=size(g);
        k=3
        for i=1:m
            j=1
            while (j<n)
                if(g(i,j)==0)
                    flag=0;
                    for w=1:k
                        if(g(i,j+w-1)==1)
                            flag=1;
                        end
                    end
                    if(flag)
                        for w=1:k
                            g(i,j+w-1)=1;
                        end
                    else
                        while(~flag&j<n)
                            j=j+1;
                            if(g(i,j)==1)
                                flag=1;
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
                j=j+1;
            end
        end
```

Is there a way to do so without all the for loops?

Comment: How do you define a "gap"? Show us an example of what you're expecting and maybe show us your for loop implementation and we can help.

Comment: I can not run your program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized version:

```
k = 3;
d = diff( g,1,2);
L = d ~= 0;
c = cumsum([zeros(size(g,1),1) L],2)+1;
b = bsxfun(@plus, c, cumsum([0; c(1:end-1,end)]));
a =accumarray(reshape(b.',[],1),1);
f= find(a<k);
g(ismember(b,f) & g==0) = 1;
```

Example :

```
g =

   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   0   0
   1   1   1   0   1
   1   1   0   0   0
   0   1   1   1   1

result = 

   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1   1
   1   1   0   0   0
   1   1   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 3):

A short version using some built-in function:

```
M = [1   1   1   1   1
     1   1   1   0   0
     1   1   1   0   1
     1   1   0   0   0
     0   1   1   1   1]

Mopen  = ~imopen(~padarray(M,[0,1],1),strel('line',3,0)); 
Mfill  = Mopen(:,2:end-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution is to cast each row to a char array and then perform substitutions based on a regular expressions

```
g = round(rand(30,70));
figure();
subplot(121);
imagesc(g)
[m,n]=size(g);
k=3;
pattern = ['(?<!',char(0),')(',char(0),'{1,',num2str(k-1),'})(?!',char(0),')'];
for i=1:m
    [matchstart,matchend] = regexp(char(g(i,:)),pattern);
    for j = 1:length(matchstart)
        g(i,matchstart(j):matchend(j)) = 1;
    end
end
subplot(122);
imagesc(g)
```